# Matrix Exponential Calculation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-exponential

I am working out of a DE textbook and am in the Matrix Exponential method for first order ODEs. I want to confirm if I am thinking about this correctly.

I am using the definition: $e^{At}$ = $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty }A^{k}\frac{t^{k}}{k!}$

For my problem I have: **X**' = $\begin{bmatrix}4& 3\\-4& -4\end{bmatrix}$**X**

(**X**' = **A** **X**)

Here, $k = 1$

$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty }A^{k}\frac{t^{k}}{k!}$ = **I** + **A**t = $\begin{bmatrix}1& 0\\0& 1\end{bmatrix}$ + $\begin{bmatrix}4& 3\\-4& -4\end{bmatrix}$t = $\begin{bmatrix}1+4t& 3t\\-4t& 1-4t\end{bmatrix}$

The general solution using this method for a homogeneous equation is: **X** = $e^{At}$**C**

**X** =  $\begin{bmatrix}1+4t\\-4t\end{bmatrix}$C1 +  $\begin{bmatrix}3t\\1-4t\end{bmatrix}$C2

When I use the method of finding Eigenvalues with corresponding Eigenvectors I get:

**X** = C1 $\begin{bmatrix}-3\\2\end{bmatrix}$$e^{2t}$ + C2 $\begin{bmatrix}-1\\2\end{bmatrix}$$e^{-2t}$ (This is the solution provided by the book.)

Can you please let me know where I am making my mistake, or if they are equivalent answers?

Comment: What do you mean when you say “Here, $k=1$”?

Comment: I dont understand why you are dropping all but the first two terms in that infinite sum?

Comment: $\exp(At)=I+At$ holds only if $A^2=O$.

Comment: Oh, I think understand now. I was thinking it would have been written as X' = A^2 X for example and k would equal 2.

Comment: There was a problem before this one where A^2 = O, and I didn't realize that. I used the incorrect thinking about k and it rolled over to this problem. I understand now. Thank you for the clarification =]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\exp(At)$ my matrix diagonalization. If $D^{-1} A D= \Lambda$, $\Lambda=diag(\lambda_1, \lambda_2)$ then $$A=D \Lambda D^{-1}, f(A)=D f(\Lambda) D^{-1}$$. In your case $$\Lambda=\begin{pmatrix} -2 & 0 \\ 0 &2 \end{pmatrix}, D= \begin{pmatrix} -1 & -3 \\ 2 & 2 \end{pmatrix}, e^{\Lambda t}= \begin{pmatrix} e^{2t} & 0 \\0 & e^{-2t}\end{pmatrix}$$
Then $$ e^{At}=\frac{1}{4}\begin{pmatrix} 2(-e^{-2t}+3e^{2t}) & -3e^{-2t}+3e^{2t} \\
4(e^{-2t}+e^{2t}) & 2(3e^{-2t}-e^{2t}) \end{pmatrix}.$$
Does this help?